# Powershell command certUtil ssh and exitCode

Tags: powershell

I have a problem with a powershell command :

```
powershell -command "& { ssh -o ServerAliveInterval=30 -o ServerAliveCountMax=2 server@server -x -p 22 CertUtil -hashfile program.jar MD5 }"
```

I've got this response :

```
CertUtil: -hashfile command FAILED: 0x80070002 (WIN32: 2 ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND)
CertUtil: The system cannot find the file specified.
```

That is the response I want. BUT this is not an error code. It is an output message. And the LastExitCode is '0'.
I need a *true* error code without analyzing the output message.
I tried to manipulate the command but without success. I don't understand why the generated error does not throw a real error in Powershell.

Comment: Try appending `; exit $LASTEXITCODE` to the existing command

Comment: That is what I've done but I've got '0'.

`powershell -command "& { ssh -o ServerAliveInterval=30 -o ServerAliveCountMax=2 server@server -x -p 22 CertUtil -hashfile program.jar MD5 }; $LastExitCode"`

`CertUtil: -hashfile command FAILED: 0x80070002 (WIN32: 2 ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND)`
`CertUtil: The system cannot find the file specified.`
`0`

Comment: First make sure `certutil` even returns a non-zero exit code for the case being.

Comment: I'am sure of that. Before powershell, I used cmd command and it works well (I had a not null exitCode error)

Comment: Why are you running this using PowerShell in the first place?

Comment: @Bill_Stewart : I have a java program which uses these commands to interact with windows servers. Previously it was implemented with cmd command but with new windows servers, cmd command is deprecated. 
And change the interaction system is not an option.

Comment: But my question is: Why do you need to run your ssh command using PowerShell (or cmd.exe) in the first place? Why not just run it directly?

Comment: @Bill_Stewart I don't understand the question. The java program needs to execute the command. It has the responsibility of communication between servers. And this is something which will not be changed.

Comment: `ssh.exe` is an executable file, just as `powershell.exe` and `cmd.exe` are executable files. Why do you need to run `ssh.exe` using `powershell.exe`? Why not just run `ssh.exe` directly? (Why is PowerShell involved at all?)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that if I use this command (with the use of execution policy), I get a non '0' exit code. It may be a goot solution even if I'm not sure of the reason why. Many thanks for your help.

```
powershell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "& ssh -o ServerAliveInterval=30 -o ServerAliveCountMax=2 server\server -x -p 22 CertUtil -hashfile program.jar MD5"; echo $LASTEXITCODE


CertUtil: -hashfile command FAILED: 0x80070002 (WIN32: 2 ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND)
CertUtil: The system cannot find the file specified.

1
```